# FileStream Reader and writer at the same time when file.exe is closing

Tags: c#

I want to write a counter in a `File.txt` whenever I close my `file.exe`.
For example at the first time I close it, it must writes 1, second time instead of 1, it must be 2, third time it must be 3 and so on.

But the problem is, at any given time, the compiler must read the number stored in the file, increment it, then write it.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms; 

namespace check
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string[] line = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
        public int i = 0;

        public Form1()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
       }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            FileStream textfile = new FileStream(@"C:\TtAL.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
            var Reader = new StreamReader(textfile);
            var Writer = new StreamWriter(textfile);
            i = Convert.ToInt32(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TtAL.txt"));
            if (File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TtAL.txt") == null) { i = -1; }
            i ++;
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\TtAL.txt", line[i]);

            MessageBox.Show(20 - Convert.ToUInt32(line[i]) + " times remained.");
            textfile.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would put that code into `using` blocks. Also, you don't need to do reading and writing at the same time. Just read the number, store it in a variable, add 1 to the variable, then write it (the `using` blocks will take care of the closing/disposing and whatnot).

Answer (score 1):

something like this will work:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;

    if (File.Exists(@"C:\TtAL.txt")) //if there is a file try to use it
    {
        if (int.TryParse(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TtAL.txt"), out i)) //if you can get a number use it
            i++;
    }

    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\TtAL.txt", i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why the `StreamWriter`? Why not just `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\TtAL.txt", i.ToString());` And by the way, there's no need to do `sw.Close()` inside a `using`.

Comment: you are correct, late in day here I'll edit it, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: thanks dudes , I just solved my problem.
true code is here:
    FileStream ABCD = new FileStream(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\TtAL.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None); StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(ABCD); StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(ABCD); int repeat = 0; do { spended_times_of_trial_mode = Convert.ToInt32(Reader.ReadLine()); spended_times_of_trial_mode++; ABCD .SetLength(0); Writer.WriteLine(spended_times.ToString()); repeat = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); } while (repeat != 0); Writer.Close();